# Как вставить логотип на шапку сайта?

Tags: html, css

Не получается вставить логотип на шапку

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="img/header.jpg">
    <img id="sm" src="img/sm.png">
    <img id="cross" src="img/cross.png">
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
margin:0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 1.6;
font-size: 16px;
}

#header{
position: relative;
}

#sm{
float: left;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 16px;
left: 176px; 
} 

#cross{
float: right;
margin-top: 96px;
right: -176px;
}
```

Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где у вас 1) таки расположена, по вашему мнению шапка и 2)какое из изображений логотип?

Comment: Может вы имеете ввиду иконку в title слева?

Comment: Они должны быть размещены на шапке. Отступы уже сделаны, нужно просто наложить их на картинку

Comment: Установите `style=position:absolute;left:0px;top;0px;` на картинке логотипа и располагайтесь  left top как вам нравится

Comment: Это для шапки установить такие значения?

Comment: @user207012 А можете показать как хочется?

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что так будет проще:

```
#header{
   background: url(img/header.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

если по быстрому то

```
<div id="header">
<img style="position:absolute;left:0px;top;0px;" src="img/header.jpg">
<img id="sm" src="img/sm.png">
<img id="cross" src="img/cross.png"></div>
```

но это большое зло
так делать нельзя
нужно не картинки использовать а background

Comment: так ответь как надо, а не показывай костыли!

Answer (score -2):

Нужно изменить порядок блоков

```
<img id="sm" src="img/sm.png">
<img id="cross" src="img/cross.png">
<img src="img/header.jpg">
```